# How to pass a variable to routing defaults in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I have a Symfony2 project with multiple brandings (subdomains). Each subdomain should use the same site functions and the same routes (with different hostname). Therefor I want to make the subdomain in the route path to a variable. Now it looks like:

```
mybundle_route:
    resource: "@MyProjectBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    host:     "{subdomain}.%base_host%"
    requirements:
        subdomain: sub1|sub2
```

and the routing itself works. But if I try to generate some routes (e.g. in twig), I get following error because no subdomain variable is set:

> Some mandatory parameters are missing ("subdomain") to generate a URL for route "company_route".

I don't want to add the parameter to each path() function in the project. 
It works perfekt for one subdomain if I add the defaults like this:

```
defaults:
    subdomain: sub1
```

but the routes are wrong for the other subdomains. Also it doesn't work with

```
defaults:
    subdomain: "%subdomain%"
```

All I need is to pass the %subdomain% variable to the defaults or to set it somewhere in the controller constructor. But I can't find the way how it is going. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: The solution with `defaults:  subdomain: %subdomain%` should work according to Symfony docs. I can see that you have a dot after pattern in `%subdomain%.`. Is it just a typo here in question or maybe it's the reason it doesn't work?

Comment: I looked into Symfony2 doc again and noticed one more difference. Try to put `%subdomain%` in double quotes - `"%subdomain%"`. Not sure if it matters, but this is how it's done in example. http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html

Comment: @dragoste  sorry, my bad. It was a typo. I don't have the dot in the script. And I tried it with and without the double quotes. If I add the defaults part to the configuration, I get following error: _The parameter "subdomain" must be defined_

Comment: Looks like it's a known issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6857 Maybe you could try to create a listener service which would set `subdomain` parameter.

Comment: @dragoste I already have one. You can't set the parameter because the ParameterBag is frozen. I already tried it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no better solution you could try to set `%subdomain%` parameter inside configuration file:

1. Create `subdomain_parameter.php` inside config folder.
2. Inside this file you have access to ther `$container` so you can manually retrieve current subdomain from the url and pass it to the container.
3. Import `subdomain_parameter.php` in the config.yml

Comment: It is a very very dirty solution. But it works - thanks. If there will be no other acceptable answer until tomorrow evening, I will accept this one.